# Bilinear Function and degenerate vs nondegenerate

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble with deciding if a function is degenerate or not.

Suppose that for each x and y in $P_n$ (polynomials) the function w is defined by $w(x,y)=x(1)y(1)$

My function is bi-linear because w(ax+bt,y)=(ax(1)+bt(1))y(1)=ax(1)y(1)+bt(1)y(1)=aw(x,y)+bw(t,y)w(ax+bt,y)=(ax(1)+bt(1))y(1)=ax(1)y(1)+bt(1)y(1)=aw(x,y)+bw(t,y).

How do I show if it is degenerate or not? Thanks.

Comment: when asking a question about degeneracy, it would be useful to clearly state what you are talking about: the form, its domain etc. What do you mean $P_n$? is the space of single variable polynomials ? Do you mean a form $\omega:P_n\times P_n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the polynomials $x\in P_n$ with $x(1) = 0$.

Comment: So x(1) would be ax(1)+bt(1)=0 ... sorry I am lost.

Comment: I believe it is degenerate but I can't say exactly why...

Comment: Can I say that w(x-1,y) = 0 ? If so how do I show the steps? I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Yes, $x(t) = t-1$ works since $w(x,y) = x(1)y(1) = 0\cdot y(1) = 0$ for each $y\in P_n$. Therefore, $w$ is degenerate. You can also use the polynomials $x(t) = t^k-1$, where $k\in\{2,\ldots,n\}$. Could you please vote for my answer so that I can at least comment on everything I want? I vote for yours. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I believe that x=t-1 works. So I would have
(t-1(1))y(1) = 0y(1)=0. It is therefore degenerate.